# Init data segment on 8051

Tags: assembly, 8051

I am a newbie in Assembly and I have a problem. I've defined data segment where I want to keep to variables of 2 bytes each. How can I set the initial value for those variables ? I'm using the simulator from Keil with 8051 uC

```
?DATAS  SEGMENT DATA

    RSEG ?DATAS ; begin data segment
cnt:     DS 2h
value:   DS 2h
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not correct: see update.

```
?DATAS  SEGMENT DATA

    RSEG ?DATAS ; begin data segment
cnt:     DW your_16bit_value_here
value:   DW your_16bit_value_here
```

---

UPDATE: sorry, the above definitions will only work for code segments.

The 8051 processor has separate memory for code and data. Code can be flashed, so data defined inside code segments can have an initial value.

On the other hand, data defined in a data segment will be stored in RAM, whose contents are not defined at bootup. Variables that need to have an initial value must be initialized from code.

Comment: I've tried that but get this: error A37: OPERATION INVALID IN THIS SEGMENT

Comment: And relative to my solution how can I init in code those two variables?